# When do I need to use _.bindAll() in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am learning backbone.js, and feel confused on this:
I am following the tutorial : 
http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/

as you can see in the first example (1.js):

```
(function($){
  var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({    
    el: $('body'), // attaches `this.el` to an existing element.

    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // fixes loss of context for 'this' within methods

       this.render(); // not all views are self-rendering. This one is.
    },

    render: function(){
      $(this.el).append("<ul> <li>hello world</li> </ul>");
    }
  });

  var listView = new ListView();      
})(jQuery);
```

But if I comment out the sentence: `_.bindAll(this, 'render');`, this will still work. I have searched in google and someone said that the method `bindAll()` is necessary since if I switched my context, the calling of `this.render` may unavailable. I feel confused on the "context". and also could some one explain me when the calling (`this.render`) will unavailable?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For the example you've given `_.bindAll(this, 'render');` isn't necessary but if you have callback functions where `this` can possibly be changed to the context of something else, then `_bindAll()` can be handy.

For instance:

```
initialize: function(){
  _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'clickFunc');
},
events: {
   'click .someElement': 'clickFunc'
},
clickFunc: function(e) {
   /** If you remove the clickFunc from the list of events in bindAll, 
          'this' will refer to the element that invoked the event.

       Adding the clickFunc event in the _.bindAll, ensures that 'this' stays
          as the view.
   */
  this /** <-- our focal point */
}
```

Comment: anything in the events has is bound automatically by backbone, FYI.

Comment: very nice explanation, great job

Answer (score 10):

- Any methods listed as property values in your view's events hash are automatically bound for you by backbone
- Any methods in your view that you manually use as event handlers from models or collections should be manually bound via `bindAll`

  - OR you can provide a context when you register the binding
  - OR you can use EMCA 5's [function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to get the same result

snippet:

```
events: {
    'click .win': 'win',
    'click .lose': 'lose'
},
initialize: function () {
    //win and lose are automatically bound for you
    //because they are in the events property

    //refresh must be manually bound
    this.model.on('change', this.refresh);

    //which you can do ECMA5 style if you like
    this.model.on('change', this.refresh.bind(this));

    //OR you can provide a context backbone style
    this.model.on('change:foo', this.fooChange, this);

    //However, since you pretty much never want an unbound function
    //in a view, you can just stick this in all your initialize methods
    //and call it done
    //Note this will bind all functions in your view class if you don't
    //pass specific method names. I recommend this form.
    _.bindAll(this);
},
win: function () {...},
lose: function () {...},
refresh: function () {...},
fooChange: function() {...}
```

...**OOOOORRRR** just use CoffeeScript and fat arrows and solve this cleanly at the language level.

Comment: I like more _.bindAll(this) also, but Underscore does not recommend it, and it won't be supported any more since 1.5.0 version. In the changelog you can read: Removed the ability to call _.bindAll with no method name arguments. It's pretty much always wiser to white-list the names of the methods you'd like to bind. http://underscorejs.org/#changelog  I think it is an error. It will me much more difficult to maintain.

Comment: @ccsakuweb I'm currently working on a web interface where I make heavy use of Backbone. In this project I currently have exactly *one* call to `_.bindAll`, and none to `_.bind`. Instead I use `this.listenTo` for listening to model events, the `events` hash for DOM events etc, and provide the context that way instead. The one `_.bindAll` call is for the `run` method of a background autorefresher, which calls `setTimeout(this.run, period)` which causes the `run` method to lose its context. Everything else to this point has been perfectly manageable without `_.bindAll`.

Answer (score 2):

in this instance you don't need the `_.bindAll`, but let's say your view have a method that causes a rerender and you do something like this:

```
..,
myMethod: function() {
    this.$('.someselector').change(this.render);
},
```

if you don't have `_.bindAll` for `render`, your context would be off.

Answer (score 2):

Lets take a close look at what `_.bindAll` does from [underscore.js offical docs](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html).

```
  _.bindAll = function(obj) {
    var i, length = arguments.length, key;
    if (length <= 1) throw new Error('bindAll must be passed function names');
    for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
      key = arguments[i];
      obj[key] = _.bind(obj[key], obj);
    }
    return obj;
  };
```

What it does is to automatically bind all its functions to its correct context. (where its function is declared rather than invoked.

I personally think it was a convention for old version of Backbone.js to bind its `events`, or DOM action listeners. Since new versions Backbone `View` automatically bind and unbind listeners in `events`. Find more by search `Binding "this"` [here](http://backbonejs.org/)

I hope it helps.