# Why use _.bindAll(this); in Backbone view?

Tags: backbone.js

What's the purpose of using `_.bindAll(this, 'render');` in the initialize function of a Backbone view?

Answer (score 0):

It's binding your functions to the right context, the context of your view. So you are sure you're not calling it by mistake in a different context.

See this : [When do I need to use _.bindAll() in Backbone.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513991/when-do-i-need-to-use-bindall-in-backbone-js)